# MongoDB - FindOne changes data type from NumberInt to decimal

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have to work with a element from my collection:

Data:

```
{ 
        "_id" : ObjectId("599ccef160b543xbf380c99x"), 
        "code" : "ME0001", 
        "description" : "Element 1", 
        "operationCode" : null, 
        "order" : NumberInt(1), 
        "level" : NumberInt(0), 
        "subItems" : [
        ]
    }
```

When I run this query to fetch the data:

```
var obj = db.itemMenu.findOne({"code": "ME0001"});
```

The problem is that the data types, of the "order" and "level" fields, change as you see:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("599ccef160b543xbf380c99x"), 
    "code" : "ME0001", 
    "description" : "Element 1", 
    "operationCode" : null, 
    "order" : 1.0, 
    "level" : 0.0, 
    "subItems" : [
    ]
}
```

How can fetch the data unchanged?

Comment: what is the problem? Question is not clear.

Comment: Are you sure your data are store as Integer in your base ? Can you show us a screenshot from MongoDB Compass or from the mongo shell ?

Comment: @new_user if you see the data, order change their format from NumberInt(1) to 1.0, that is my problem, I want to avoid that situation

Comment: @Nicolas it's store such as Int32 in my database

Comment: it's weird, you can always use parseInt in your code after, but the find method is not supposed to edit the data.

Comment: So, what should I do to update my data?

Answer (score 0):

Use Schema's to allow only integers: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/

To update all float to ints:

```
db.itemMenu.find( {  } ).forEach( function (item) {   
  item.order = parseInt(item.order); // convert field to int
  item.level = parseInt(item.level); // convert field to int
  db.itemMenu.save(item);
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: But in this case I have to do that for each element in whole my document, I mean subItems as well.

Comment: As asked in the question, this code snippet helps you convert level and order as int. It should give an idea of how to do it.